# Differences between PHP 5.2.x and 5.3.x with respect to the SOAP library

Tags: php, soap-client, windows-server

I have developed a PHP site using PHP 5.3.4 and deployed it to a server that has PHP 5.2.6 installed. I am not doing anything fancy; in fact, the only major library I am using is PHP's native SOAP library.

However, when I test my deployed site, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in (path) on line 20
```

Are there any major differences between PHP 5.2.x and 5.3.x with respect to the SOAP library? I have already changed the configuration files. (Well, actually I told the sysadmin to do it, because I don't have permission to do so.) And I get the same error. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:** More information...

1. I'm deploying my site to a Windows server.
2. The server has AppServ installed.
3. For some reason I don't understand, PHP's configuration file is `C:\Windows\php.ini` instead of `PHP_DIR\php.ini`.

Comment: Do you have the soap extension enabled in the relevant php.ini?

Comment: I had it installed. Although it doesn't matter, because I have just fully reinstalled AppServ

Comment: Never mind. I uninstalled AppServ and installed the Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.5 separately.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think soap is installed on the server try

```
sudo aptitude install php-soap
```

Comment: I'm deploying my site to a Windows server. And I do have the SOAP dll (`PHP_DIR/ext/php_soap.dll`)

Answer (score 0):

change the following line in php.ini:

```
;extension=php_soap.dll // before
extension=php_soap.dll // after
```

this enables the soap extension since PHP 5.0